# How can I improve my code with classes and methods?

Tags: ruby, class, oop, object

i have this code in Ruby made to search words through any webpage.

I wonder if it's possible to improve it with Class/Methods, make it more beautiful and functional using Object Oriented. Anyone could help me, please?

```
require 'open-uri'

puts "Type URL you wanna search:"
url = gets.chomp
puts "Type the word you want to search:"
pattern = gets.chomp   

page = open(url.to_s).read
tags = page.scan(pattern)

puts "It has #{tags.length} matches for: #{pattern} "
```

Comment: If your code runs correctly please consider moving your question to [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things you can do to improve this. The first is to encapsulate the functionality inside a descriptive class:

```
class PageParser
  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
  end

  def scan(word)
    open(@url).read.scan(word)
  end
end
```

I'd also strongly recommend steering towards a more command-line friendly interface. This makes running repeated tests trivial, you can usually up-arrow, run the last command over, no input necessary:

```
url, word = ARGV

puts PageParser.new(url).scan(word).join(', ')
```

You can build on that with [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) to make it more robust, adding flags like `--verbose` and what have you.

Comment: I didnt get it where the user gonna input the url and the word on your code. (newbie here srry)

Comment: Like this: `ruby myscript.rb http://example.com tag` on the command-line. If you can get the script to auto-execute, even easier: `myscript http://example.com/ tag`

Comment: Don't know if you're still there. You know how to exclude html tags from this scan? Because i got some words in the page that have name in classes too :x

Comment: Use an HTML parser like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) or something like it to extract the text you want, then `scan` that. It works a lot like jQuery with CSS selectors.

Comment: Is there anyway to remove only everything inside <head> without  using Nokogiri?

Comment: You'll need an HTML parser of some variety to do that reliably.

Comment: i'm getting crazy here hahahaha i just need to remove <head> but its been kinda hard to do this and i don't have that much experience on this. I've got a regex that helped me in body, but i'm still lose at <head> and I didnt really understanf Nokogiri, it seems to me that he gets data like i'm doing, but specifically... And i didnt get How can i make it work together with my code]

Comment: Here's an [example that removes `<head>`](https://gist.github.com/tadman/93e0764fe8975ec74cd2e08643941c02). It's pretty simple.

Comment: Hmm, ok That's pretty awesome omg. I'm feeling so dumb, saw your example but I don't know where to fit inside the code. Should I create a method for it and put @url inside of DATA?

Sorry for all the questions i've just started on last Friday on ruby >.<

Comment: I have this... Just dont know where to put that Nogokiri code :C [my code](https://gist.github.com/MoscrowDev/a3a34b4f2cdafdc3e3e6e2010c2cf640)

Comment: Oh, instead of `DATA` you can put in any old string, like `open(@url).read` would do it.